# Function for multiple line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have written the function for plotting a line graph.

```
def plt1(plot,xaxis,yaxis):

    plt.title('Distribution of {yaxis} across {xaxis}'.format(xaxis=xaxis, yaxis=yaxis))
    plt.ylabel(yaxis)
    plt.xlabel(xaxis)
    plt.legend(df.columns.values)
    plt.savefig("C:\\User\\folder\\plot.csv")
    plt.show()
    return(plt);

plt1(df,'x','y')
```

Now I need to make multiple line chart that has same x axis and different columns of the same csv file as y axis (different colors for different columns).Except for the y-axis value, the rest of the formats remain the same. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I would need something similar to this graph
[image]

Comment: I'm sure google charts have better options,but I wanted to do this in python.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you face? `plt.plot` can draw a line, using `plt.plot` several times will produce several lines. What else do you need or in how far is this not working?

Comment: My doubt is how to pass different y-axis into the function and generate multiple lines in same chart.I have added a image now . The different y-axis are the different columns from the same csv file

Comment: *Try* to pass several column names to your function, and *use* `plt.plot` of `df.plot` in your function. If an error occurs or if it doesn't look as expected, ask specifically about the problem you face.

Comment: @Unknown Have you had a look at the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) or the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) to see if you can adapt one of the existing scripts?